# Know any embeddable NNTP servers?

Tags: java, unit-testing, nntp

I'm writing a bit of code that uses the [Apache NNTP Client](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/nntp/NNTPClient.html) to fetch articles from an NNTP server. Once the code ships, we'll use an Apache James server to read the articles from. But to test the code, I'm looking for an embedded Java NNTP server, so I don't have to mock every server call. Are there any good ones I can use? Google seems to have failed me.

My requirements are as follows:

1. A server I can start from within the code.
2. Tests can be run out-of-the-box on different machines without additional setup. (Once I commit the code, a remote build machine needs to be able to run the test cases).

Any other inspired suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: No, I didn't. The closest I found was an in-development program here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=159154291

Answer (score 1):

There is [sonews](https://github.com/chrlns/sonews), which seems to be active and supports a suprising lot of database backends. I didn't look at it further, so I can't tell if you can embed it.